# overleaf coding error fixation

Tags: errors, overleaf

Though my PDF is generated still I am getting these errors. Please help me to fix it up

[image: Latex error]

Comment: surely the text you show shows how to fix each case.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: From where to change the error"The starred command '\DeclareDelimAlias*' is deprecated. Use the unstarred version '\DeclareDelimAlias' instead." I am using overleaf platform

Comment: for the middle one, the log file message shows the list of options to delete,

Comment: it is in your document, the warning message you show has a link to it, or simply search

Comment: they are not error,but warnings

Comment: and what about this : 'Overfull \hbox (2.32614pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 185--188'
Any package is being missed or what

Comment: again that is specfiic to your text on that line, not any package, tex could not find a good linebreak